# In Angular, how to detect that input was changed by 3rd party code?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have done a few examples in Angular where I do something in response to the user keying data into an input element.

I use the following code in my link function to detect and respond to changes:

```
            $element.bind("keyup", listener);
            $element.bind("change", listener);
            $element.bind('paste cut', function () {
                $browser.defer(listener);
            });
```

This works great with one big exception.  I am using the Kendo UI datepicker directive on the same input to allow the user to select a date on a calendar.  When the user changes the date by clicking on the calendar, the change event is not caught by my code.

The fact that I'm using Kendo UI is arbitrary; I suppose I should expect this problem with any 3rd party Javascript code.

How can I wire up my link function so that it sees that a field changes when modified by other Javascript code?

**Edit:** As requested, here is a simplified example of the problem.  It is a page that contains a text field and a button.  The text field is wired up with Angular to pop an alert box when the contents of the field is changed.  The button changes the value of the field manually, and Angular won't do anything.  I want it to detect this change and respond with a pop-up just the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    When you type something in the box focus away from the input, Angular code pops an alert box.
    <br />
    <input
        id="foo"        
        alert />
    <input
        type="button"
        value="But click this button to change the contents of the box and no alert happens." 
        onclick="document.getElementById('foo').value = 'bar';"/>
    <script>
        angular.module("myApp", [])
        .controller("myController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
            $scope.foo = "foo";
        }])
        .directive('alert', ['$browser',function ($browser) {
            return {                
                link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {                    
                    function listener() {
                        alert("listener function invoked!");
                    }                    
                    $element.bind("change", listener);
                    $element.bind('paste cut', function () {
                        $browser.defer(listener);
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you produce a case to replicate this problem?

Comment: Yes, you should expect that with any third party javascript code. Datepicker from bootstrap -> same problem. I have not solved this problem myself, but doing something with watches should do the trick. Sorry, that is what I remember...Also you can try to set the `$modelValue` manually

Comment: Why use `$element.bind` rather than the `ng-keyup` and other event handling directives (that still work with the Kendo DatePicker)?

Comment: @Mikey, you suggest using watches.  In the examples I've found, the watch is set from the controller and watches a controller scope value.  How can I set a watch on the model value from my directive code?

Comment: Angularjs has a dirty checking mechanism which causes a digest.   This automatic dirty checking doesn't occur for external events such as Sockets, non-angular custom code, or 3rd party code like KendoUI. This will require you to manually trigger a digest ($digest or $watch will trigger a dirty check.).

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon You can require `ngModel` in a directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer using the comments above as guidance.  I will edit this to be more complete later, but the short answer is to require ngModel and attach a $watch to it.

Answer (score 0):

making DOM changes in that way is against angular philosophy, we leave the directives for this, that is why angular doesnot catch the button change, i mean on that point:

```
<input
        type="button"
        value="But click this button to change the contents of the box and no alert happens." 
        onclick="document.getElementById('foo').value = 'bar';"/>
```

**You would better do (just HTML & angular here):**

```
/*without directive*/
<input type="text" id="foo" ng-model="foo" />
<input type="button" value="Change value" onclick="changeVal()"/>
```

**Into controller(i added a $watch)**

```
.controller("myController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
            $scope.foo = "foo";

            //when button pressed
            $scope.changeVal() = function{
              $scope.foo = "new value";
            };

       //when the foo value change, the $watch catch it
       $scope.$watch('foo', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            var newValue = newVal;
            if (newVal != oldVal) {
               alert("value changed");
              //add here whatever code ..
            }
        });

    }])
```